# How to save mutiple depandent modals in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What is the best practice to save multiple dependent modals in elegant way. The code below works fine but is there any other way? I am just trying to make that function cleaner and smaller

```
//Controller store method
$customer = Customer::create(['nae' => $request->name, 'password' => Hash::make($pass)]);
$books = new Book();
$books->customer_id = $customer->id;
$books->name = $request->name;
...
$books->save();

$chapters = new Chapter();
$chapters->book_id = $books->id;
$chapters->name = $request->name;
...
$chapters->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so SQL have any Inner Query for insertion like ( Select Query ) to Insert Data into Tables
by the way, the best approach to do the Code

```
$data = [
    ['id'=>'Coder 1', 'subject_id'=> 221],
    ['id'=>'Coder 2', 'subject_id'=> 222],

];

Chapter::insert($data);
```